# how to get keyword cloud from mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have many documents in the following format

```
{
    _id:...,
    words:["usa","canda","america", "colon"],
    owner:23
}
{
    _id:...,
    words:["chile","peru","argentina","america", "colon"],
    owner:23
}
{
    _id:...,
    words:["colon", "america", "britain", "mexico", "usa"],
    owner:23
}
```

So, i need keyword cloud from owner `23`:

```
[
    {name:"america", hits:3},
    {name:"colon", hits:3},
    {name:"usa", hits:2},
    {name:"britain", hits:1},
    {...}
]
```

My problem is that I can not get what I want.
How i can get?
thanks

Comment: Aggregation Pipeline will help you here. Read up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** which will give you what you are after. The aggregation pipeline should have the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** operator as the first step which filters the input documents on the `owner` key that has value 23.
The second pipeline step is the **[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator which deconstructs the `words` array field from the input documents and outputs for the next stream a document for each element. Each output document replaces the array with an element value.

The pipeline stage that gives you the keyword count is the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator which groups input documents from the previous stream by the `word` key and applies the accumulator expression **[`$sum`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum)** that returns a sum for each group.

The last step, **[`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator reshapes each document in the stream by adding a new field `name` which replaces the `_id` key from the previous stream.

In the end, your aggregation pipeline would look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "owner": 23 }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$words"
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$words",
            "hits": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "name": "$_id", "hits": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Oh, I had managed to do something relatively similar, but not so well done. Many thanks!

Comment: @OlafErlandsen Cheers! Feel free to accept the answer if that's helped, but there's no obligation in doing so.